# Should I use a passive or an active filter?

Tags: amplifier, rf, filter, antenna, radio

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fINGfA.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

I need to design an am receiver as a project. On the front end I have three modules; BPF1 the "roofing filter" or the "pre-select filter", BPF2 to further "protect" the demodulator, and an RF amplifier between these two filters. Should my filters be passive or active?

The block diagram above shows what I am designing.

Comment: I'm pretty sure that an amplifier has to be active.

Comment: That was a typo, I meant filters.

Comment: At first, you should decide what kind of filter (I assume bandpass) and which bandwidth (selectivity, order of the filter).

Comment: Bandpass filter, with bandwidth of 10 kHz, center frequency of 1080 kHz.

Comment: So you require a quality factor Q=108 around 1MHz ! For passive realizations you need a high-quality inductance. And for active realizations an opamp with a gain-bandwidth product of at least 100MHz.

Answer (score 2):

In traditional radio, pretty much all the filters are passive because historically, none of the amplifying devices had enough gain-bandwidth for a satisfactory active filter. So active filters here are a departure from tradition - but with high speed opamps, possibly a feasible one.

In any case, any filter before the first amplifier has to be passive by definition! You can combine a passive filter with an amplifier stage - i.e. a tuned load. Active filters tend to have higher noise levels, so best not applied to low level signals.

Also note that - answering LvW's comment about a Q of 108 - filters ahead of the mixer are usually relatively wide bandwidth, determined by whatever Q you can economically achieve.  Most filtering happens after the mixer, at the (generally lower) Intermediate Frequency (IF) - traditionally 455-470 kHz..

Because the local oscillator is tuned, the IF is constant so the narrow bandwidth (10kHz in your case) is a fixed filter. And because the IF is usually a lower frequency, the Q and GBW required are lower.

So you could employ passive filtering at RF, and a fixed frequency high order filter at IF, and nowadays the latter could be either passive or active.

For completeness, some radio systems use a high IF, perhaps 10.7 MHz, with extremely high-Q (passive!) filters made using quartz crystals as bandpass filter elements instead of their normal role in oscillators. Some also use more that one IF - a first IF at 10.7 MHz and a second at the traditional 455kHz.