# How do I overlap wires in OrCAD capture without having the two wires have a node?

Tags: schematics, wire, layout, orcad, allegro

I'm doing a schematic for [this](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/153830/should-i-use-a-passive-or-an-active-filter) in OrCAD capture CIS. In laying out my schematic I need to draw one wire going through another wire, but not necessarily intersecting with it via a node. When I drag a wire through it it automatically creates a node there at the intersection. Is there a way to draw these two wires overlapping but without a node?

Comment: I can't exactly tell from your question if you want the wires connected or not. Can you make that more clear?

Comment: I don't want the wires connected, but when I drag a wire over another wire (they're perpendicular to each other) a node is created.

Comment: Ah, that's not normal behavior unless it's the case Andy describes below.

Answer (score 4):

I use orcad 16 and if you drag a wire that crosses another wire where that wire connects to a component it will justifiably make a connection. Just ensure that dragged wires don't intersect at component terminations.

Comment: You answered this twice... but you're right, I was dragging over a component terminal.

Comment: Looks like a glitch dude

Answer (score 2):

I was looking for an answer to remove a junction and found 
http://www-3.unipv.it/ele1/pspice/pspice91/capqrc.pdf 
where shift key is used in various operations.So I gave it a shot:)

1. Click on a junction icon in toolbar (two lines normal to each other).
2. Hold shift and click on a junction.
3. Junction is gone/deleted.

Answer (score 0):

If Orcad makes a connection between two crossing wires it puts a little dot there so you know.  They call it a junction I think, so if you don't see the dot you should be ok.  If you want to make them connect there is a button to add a junction.  It's in your standard tool bar, looks like a cross with a red dot in the middle.  You can click that then use that tool to click on sections of wire that overlap or cross over and it will create a junction or connection for you.

Hope that helps some.  You can always do a netlist check to see what's really happening.